# using a disk allocator for std::deque

Tags: c++, memory, std

How can I store the contents of std::deque onto disk? I found that you can specify an allocator i.e.

```
std::deque<std::unique_ptr<my_struct>>, disk_allocator<std::unique_ptr<my_struct>>> q;
```

How can I write a custom allocator "disk_allocator" to store on disk? Does one already exist in the std library?

Comment: The scope of your question is huge. The answer section is likely not big enough to explain everything involved in writing a virtual memory mapped allocator. It is better to ask about a more specific problem.

Comment: For example, which part of writing your allocator are you having trouble with? Have you consulted any documentation explaining how allocators work?

Comment: No, there is no such allocator in the standard library.

Comment: Have you considered serializing the data, instead? If you just want the contents, that should be much easier. But still a big topic.

Comment: You can try STXXL library (https://stxxl.org/) - it does not support deque, but you may find another suitable container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disk Based Dynamic Memory Allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724096/disk-based-dynamic-memory-allocation)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with [metal](https://github.com/LLNL/metall). It's a bit awkward to plainly suggest a library since this is a huge topic, and to be sure that a solution does what you want/need it's important to dive into the concepts of individual problems solved by allocators, memory mapping, persistence, serialization and friends (I have linked sources on those topics in the question comments).

That been said, metal would be used like so:

```cpp
// Example for deque<int>
using namespace metall;
namespace mc = metall::container;
using deque_t = deque<int, metall::allocator<int>>;

void create_data()
{
  manager mg(create_only, "/tmp/dir");
  // storage location      ^^^^^^^^ 

  deque_t* p = mg.construct<deque_t>("deque")(mg.get_allocator());
  p->push_back(10); // Can use it normally
}

void reattach_data()
{
  manager mg(create_only, "/tmp/dir");
  // storage location      ^^^^^^^^ 

  deque_t* p = mg.find<deque_t>("deque").first;
  p->push_back(10); // Can resume work
}
```

You can check the related [examples](https://github.com/LLNL/metall/blob/master/example/metall_containers.cpp) for Standard Library interoperability.

If you are willing to go with serialization, [cereal](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/) has bindings for most standard library containers including [deque](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal/blob/master/include/cereal/types/deque.hpp).

Answer (score 0):

You can't allocate from disk in order to be used with `std::deque`. At least it's not how we store STL Container data into the disk. The STL [Allocators'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) job is to encapsulate strategies for access/addressing, allocation/deallocation, and construction/destruction of objects.

For storing simple container data in the disk we could do:
 <sub>for copy/paste and test: [serialize_deserialize_example](https://github.com/another-ghasem/examples/blob/master/sub_examples/serialize_deserialize_simple/source/main.cpp#L58)</sub>

```cpp
template<typename Container>
void save_to_disk(Container const& container, std::filesystem::path const& path)
{
    std::ofstream output(path);
    if(!output.is_open())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't open file: " + path.string());
    }

    for(auto const& item : container)
    {
        output << item << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But obviously, we don't have always that must simple data structure to simply converted to string and back. For serialization of STL Containers I suggest using [Boost.Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html):
 <sub>for copy/paste and test: [boost_serialize_deserialize](https://github.com/another-ghasem/examples/blob/master/sub_examples/boost_serialize_deserialize/source/main.cpp#L67)</sub>

```cpp
struct my_structure final
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    std::deque<std::string> data;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int const)
    {
        ar& data;
    }
};
```